# How to reset a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

```
<apex:page id="page1">
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryA, 'js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryA, 'js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js')}"/>
<apex:form id="form1">
<apex:inputtext value="{!text1}"/>
<apex:inputtext value="{!text2}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Reset" onclick="myFunction();"/>
<apex:commandButton value="List" action="{!list}"/>
<script>
    function myFunction()
        {
        document.getElementById('form1').reset();
        alert("Sundhar");
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

i have two button are there first button is to reset and second button is to show list .when i click on the reset button before click the list it is reset the form when i click the reset button after clicking the list it is not working.i need that mainly it has to reset after clicking the list button

Comment: `form1` should be enclosed with `'form1'`

Comment: Just reload the page when the reset button is clicked.. It can be done in javascript using the history object --> history.go();

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to quote the id so use this:

```
document.getElementById('form1').reset()
```